# OpenLayers - Style label ignores plus sign

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a OpenLayers.Style like this :

```
PoisStyle = new OpenLayers.Style({
    ...
    label: "${poiLabel}"
}, {
    context: {
        ...
        poiLabel: function(feature) {
            return "+212011223344";
        }
    }
});
```

But the + in `+212011223344` gets ignored, all that shows is `212011223344`.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

During evaluation the method `OpenLayers.Style.createLiteral` is called, which contains this line:

```
value=(isNaN(value)||!value)?value:parseFloat(value);
```

The content of your string is classified as **not** being "not a number", therefore feed to `parseFloat` which returns a number, and this number is converted to a string without a leading "+". Same way you would loose trailing zeros.

As quick fix you may insert a zero width nonbreak space into your literal:

```
return "+\ufeff212011223344";
```

This makes the string "not a number" w/o being visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try the ASCII code instead:

```
&#43;
```